# Извлечь из текста поста отрывок

Tags: php, php7

Есть посты типа:

Заказ выполнен Выполнена индивидуальная гравировка на ручке. Хотите такую же, пишите или приходите к нам. #хештеги

Заказ выполнен Изготовлен такой-то предмет. Хотите такой же, пишите или приходите к нам. #хештеги

Принцип построения данных постов такой: какие-то символы (или эмоджи), фраза "Заказ выполнен", какие-то закрывающие символы (или эмоджи). После идёт именно описание того, что выполнено (до точки), далее не особо важный текст и хештеги. И вот тут столкнулся с проблемой. Если бы все описания начинались со слова "Выполнена", то проблем разложить данный пост на Название (Заказ выполнен) и Описание (Выполнена индивидуальная гравировка на ручке) нет. Но выяснилось, что возможны и другие формулировки.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить данный момент, как разложить данные посты на Название, Описание и хештеги. Заранее благодарю всех за помощь.

Comment: использовать регулярки

Answer (score 0):

как-нибудь так, видимо?

```
if(preg_match('/Заказ выполнен.*?\s(.+?)\./iu', $input, $m)){
    echo $m[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем решил данный вопрос след образом:

```
preg_grep('/[\s,]+/m', explode("\n", $string))
```

вроде как пока всё работает